# npm moment vs classic js date formats efficiency

Tags: javascript, npm

I recreated a basic page to try npm packages, in particular npm moment, following this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Rmj5UY5mJk

However I got a bundle.js file with 5680 lines of js, so I wondered:
Isn't it more efficient (faster loading times) to just use these formats:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

or even just create your own with a simple js function that just changes the data to the wanted format?

Comment: The major improvement that third-party libraries bring is a saner time API and support for internationalized date/time formats (not everyone speaks English and/or writes dates and times in the same format). However for the second part there [is an API that might become common enough soon enough](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat).

Comment: Dates are far from trivial. There are other libraries that are more modular than moment also so you can import only what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`moment` is super large because it includes all locales by default.

[image]

To have the ability to manipulate time, I suggest `dayjs`, it doesn't includes all locales by default. But you still got all the date/time manipulation power.

[image]